# Не создается сокет на Java

Tags: java, сокет, стек, сетевое-программирование

Я совсем новичок в программировании и передо мной встала такая проблема. Обучаюсь по книге "Изучаем Java". Пишу приложение-чат. Создаю сокет на локальном хосте

```
Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
```

и у меня вылетает исключение

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
    at DailyAdviceClient.go(DailyAdviceClient.java:11)
    at DailyAdviceClient.main(DailyAdviceClient.java:29)
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

В интернет туториалах предлагают тоже самое что и в книгах. 127.0.0.1 является так называемой заглушкой для тестов программы, т.е. должно работать без сервера.
Вот пример программы

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceClient {
    public void go(){
        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            String advice = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Сегодня ты должен: "+advice);
            reader.close();

        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DailyAdviceClient client =new DailyAdviceClient();
        client.go();
    }
}
```

Comment: А сервер по адресу 127.0.0.1:4242 уже ждёт запрос?

Comment: Точно ответить на данный вопрос не могу. Но разве мой компьютер не является сервером сам для себя?

Comment: Вы должны создать и запусить сервер. То, что вы показываете - это клиентская часть. Шаблонов в интернете можно найти массу, вот например туториал от Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: В туториалась пишут все тоже самое что и в книгах.

Comment: Все, разобрался. И правда надо было делать сервер =) этот сайт помог.
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/654-klassih-socket-i-serversocket-ili-allo-server-tih-menja-slihshishjh